# How to save multiple text input in different .txt file

Tags: java, text, user-input

I have made a program, which allows users to have as many text boxes as they want in which they can input a text string. I want to save each user input into different variables. I also want to print all of those variable or access the data stored in them when ever I want.

If you can help me that it would be really nice, thanks in advance. If you have any question please let me know in comment and I will answer them.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class GUI
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField tfield;
    private String nameTField;
    private int count;
    public GUI()
    {
        nameTField = "tField";
        count = 0;
    }
    private void displayGUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2, 2));
        button = new JButton("Add Another");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                tfield = new JTextField();
                tfield.setName(nameTField + count);
                count++;
                frame.add(tfield);
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });
        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new GUI().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an `ArrayList<String>`.

Declare a `private ArrayList<String> userStrings;` where you have your private fields.

In your constructor, add `userStrings = new ArrayList<String>();`

And then when you receive a string, just add it into your list with `userStrings.add(myNewString)`.  (Use your String instead of `myNewString`)

ArrayLists are indexed like an array, but using a method `get`, so you can get the first item in your list by using `userStrings.get(0)`.